# Md-dialog dysfunction trigger button wrapped within md-dialog controller

Tags: angularjs, mddialog

I followed [documentation](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/dialog) to produce working md-dialog, but I've stuck on dysfunctional button, which triggers dialog. Once dialog opened and closed, the trigger button (everything that uses script within that controller) appears not doing it's job.

Here is [CodePen](http://codepen.io/DominikK/pen/mPYoZb) and code.

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngMaterial', 'ngAnimate']);

// Dialog controller
app.controller('showDialogCtrl',
  function ($scope, $mdDialog) {
    // Showing order form dialog
    $scope.showDialog= function($event){
      $mdDialog.show({
         targetEvent: $event,
         clickOutsideToClose: true,
         scope: $scope,
         template: 
            '<md-dialog>' +
            '  <md-dialog-content>Hello!</md-dialog-content>' +
            '  <md-dialog-actions>' +
            '    <md-button ng-click="closeDialog()" class="md-primary">' +
            '      Close' +
            '    </md-button>' +
            '  </md-dialog-actions>' +
            '</md-dialog>',
         parent: angular.element(document.body),
         controller: DialogController,
      });
      function DialogController($scope, $mdDialog) {
        $scope.closeDialog = function() {
          $mdDialog.hide();
        };
      };
    }
});    

<md-button ng-controller="showDialogCtrl" ng-click="showDialog($event)">
Click
</md-button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing the parent `$scope` to your dialog, which gets automatically removed when you close the dialog. Add `preserveScope: true` to your dialog config so it won't get deleted once you close the dialog.

Docs: https://material.angularjs.org/HEAD/api/service/$mdDialog

Comment: I know we shouldn't thank in comment, but they could make a muted way to thank person who gave correct answer. I feel better than. Thanks! :)